# Resample curve into even length segments using C++

Tags: c++, math, polyline

What would be the best way of resampling a curve into even length segments using C++? What I have is a set of points that represents a 2d curve. In my example below I have a point struct with x and y components and a vector of points with test positions. Each pair of points represents a segment on the curve. Example resample curves are the images below. The red circles are the original positions the green circles are the target positions after the resample.

[image: Resample 1] [image]

```
struct Point
{
    float x, y;
};


std::vector<Point> Points;
int numPoints = 5;

float positions[] = {
0.0350462,  -0.0589667,
0.0688311,  0.240896,
0.067369,   0.557199,
-0.024258,  0.715255,
0.0533231,  0.948694,
};

// Add points
int offset = 2;
for (int i =0; i < numPoints; i++)
{
    offset = i * 2;
    Point pt;
    pt.x = positions[offset];
    pt.y = positions[offset+1];
    Points.push_back(pt);

}
```

Comment: The best way to perform that interpolation depends on the nature of your data and how precise you need it to be. I'd start by googling linear and spline interpolations to see if they'll do what you need them to.

Comment: Which book on computer graphics are you using to learn the subject?

Comment: If I resample by edge it is quite easy just to displace or lerp  from current point to  next. What I cannot figure out is doing it for the whole curve.

Comment: You can use [b-splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline) or [Bézier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve), for example.

Comment: It is not splines or bezier it is still a poly curve. I added images to describe the problem better.

Comment: In the images, consecutive points in the resampling seem to be separated by the same distance along a linear interpolation of the source, however the Euclidean distance between these points varies, because more "bendy" segments from the source produce shorter segments in the result.  Are you asking for this, or do you want all consecutive points in the result to be equidistant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if this works for you.  Resampled points are equidistant from each other on the linear interpolation of the source vector's points.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

struct Point {
    double x, y;
};

// Distance gives the Euclidean distance between two Points
double Distance(const Point& a, const Point& b) {
    const double dx = b.x - a.x;
    const double dy = b.y - a.y;
    const double lsq = dx*dx + dy*dy;
    return std::sqrt(lsq);
}

// LinearCurveLength calculates the total length of the linear
// interpolation through a vector of Points.  It is the sum of
// the Euclidean distances between all consecutive points in
// the vector.
double LinearCurveLength(std::vector<Point> const &points) {
    auto start = points.begin();
    if(start == points.end()) return 0;
    auto finish = start + 1;
    double sum = 0;
    while(finish != points.end()) {
        sum += Distance(*start, *finish);
        start = finish++;
    }
    return sum;
}

// Gives a vector of Points which are sampled as equally-spaced segments
// taken along the linear interpolation between points in the source.
// In general, consecutive points in the result will not be equidistant,
// because of a corner-cutting effect.
std::vector<Point> UniformLinearInterpolation(std::vector<Point> const &source, std::size_t target_count) {
    std::vector<Point> result;
    if(source.size() < 2 || target_count < 2) {
        // degenerate source vector or target_count value
        // for simplicity, this returns an empty result
        // but special cases may be handled when appropriate for the application
        return result;
    }
    // total_length is the total length along a linear interpolation
    // of the source points.
    const double total_length = LinearCurveLength(source);

    // segment_length is the length between result points, taken as
    // distance traveled between these points on a linear interpolation
    // of the source points.  The actual Euclidean distance between
    // points in the result vector can vary, and is always less than
    // or equal to segment_length.
    const double segment_length = total_length / (target_count - 1);

    // start and finish are the current source segment's endpoints
    auto start = source.begin();
    auto finish = start + 1;

    // src_segment_offset is the distance along a linear interpolation
    // of the source curve from its first point to the start of the current
    // source segment.
    double src_segment_offset = 0;

    // src_segment_length is the length of a line connecting the current
    // source segment's start and finish points.
    double src_segment_length = Distance(*start, *finish);

    // The first point in the result is the same as the first point
    // in the source.
    result.push_back(*start);

    for(std::size_t i=1; i<target_count-1; ++i) {
        // next_offset is the distance along a linear interpolation
        // of the source curve from its beginning to the location
        // of the i'th point in the result.
        // segment_length is multiplied by i here because iteratively
        // adding segment_length could accumulate error.
        const double next_offset = segment_length * i;

        // Check if next_offset lies inside the current source segment.
        // If not, move to the next source segment and update the
        // source segment offset and length variables.
        while(src_segment_offset + src_segment_length < next_offset) {
            src_segment_offset += src_segment_length;
            start = finish++;
            src_segment_length = Distance(*start, *finish);
        }
        // part_offset is the distance into the current source segment
        // associated with the i'th point's offset.
        const double part_offset = next_offset - src_segment_offset;

        // part_ratio is part_offset's normalized distance into the 
        // source segment. Its value is between 0 and 1,
        // where 0 locates the next point at "start" and 1
        // locates it at "finish".  In-between values represent a
        // weighted location between these two extremes.
        const double part_ratio = part_offset / src_segment_length;

        // Use part_ratio to calculate the next point's components
        // as weighted averages of components of the current
        // source segment's points.
        result.push_back({
            start->x + part_ratio * (finish->x - start->x),
            start->y + part_ratio * (finish->y - start->y)
        });
    }

    // The first and last points of the result are exactly
    // the same as the first and last points from the input,
    // so the iterated calculation above skips calculating
    // the last point in the result, which is instead copied
    // directly from the source vector here.
    result.push_back(source.back());
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Point> points = {
        { 0.0350462,  -0.0589667},
        { 0.0688311,   0.240896 },
        { 0.067369,    0.557199 },
        {-0.024258,    0.715255 },
        { 0.0533231,   0.948694 }
    };

    std::cout << "Source Points:\n";
    for(const auto& point : points) {
        std::cout << std::setw(14) << point.x << "    " << std::setw(14) << point.y << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    auto interpolated = UniformLinearInterpolation(points, 7);
    std::cout << "Interpolated Points:\n";
    for(const auto& point : interpolated) {
        std::cout << std::setw(14) << point.x << "    " << std::setw(14) << point.y << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "Source linear interpolated length:           " << LinearCurveLength(points) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Interpolation's linear interpolated length:  " << LinearCurveLength(interpolated) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: You solution works quite well. Just one question  is there a way to optimize this part `while(src_segment_offset + src_segment_length < next_offset) ` Instead of this to use a map?

Comment: @sabotage3d There is a redundant addition operation here, which I'm pretty sure the optimizer takes care of.  But, off the top of my head, I don't see how a map could help here.  Could you let me know your ideas about using a map here?  Thanks.

Comment: @sabotage3d Maybe what you have in mind is that this linear search through consecutive source points could be replaced by something more optimized, like a keyed lookup?

Comment: What I am thinking but I could be wrong, if we fit in range from 0 to 1 the current point distance a sum of all previous segments from the total length we should get normalized range. Then we should be able to map this range by the position of the point.

Comment: Your idea is valid.  The problem is that the cost of setting up the table of normalized source segment ranges is equivalent to doing the linear search.  Also keep in mind that this linear search is bounded -- it begins at the "current" source segment.  In the case of subsampling, its average iteration count is less than one.  In the supersampling case, there may be an optimization opportunity, but I'm guessing it would be rather complicated.  There is one place which lends itself to optimization in this code, but I didn't want to add extra complexity to this example....

Comment: Note that `Distance` for each source segment is calculated twice, once in a call to `LinearCurveLength`, then again during the interpolation.  So the obvious optimization would be to cache this value, and maybe also each segment's starting offset.

Comment: @sabotage3d I mixed up "sub-" and "super-" sampling above, but you know what I mean.

Comment: Thank you very much. The code and the method work great.

Answer (score 1):

For green points equidistant along the polyline:

The first run: walk through point list, calculate length of every segment and cumulative length up to current point. Pseudocode:

```
cumlen[0] = 0;
for (int i=1; i < numPoints; i++) {
   len = Sqrt((Point[i].x - Point[i-1].x)^2 + (Point[i].y - Point [i-1].y)^2)
   cumlen[i] = cumlen[i-1] + len; 
}
```

Now find length of every new piece

```
plen = cumlen[numpoints-1] / numpieces;
```

Now the second run -  walk through point list and insert new points in appropriate segments.

```
i = 0;
for (ip=0; ip<numpieces; ip++) {
   curr = plen * ip;
   while cumlen[i+1] < curr
     i++;
   P[ip].x = Points[i].x + (curr - cumlen[i]) * (Points[i+1].x - Points[i].x) / 
                            (cumlen[i+1] - cumlen[i]);
    ..the same for y
}
```

Examples of real output for `numpieces > numPoints` and vice versa

[image]

Comment: There is something wrong in the pseudocode I cannot get it to work correctly. Also would this approach work if we want to reduce the number of the original segments?

Comment: Changed code to `while cumlen[i+1]`. Approach should work if numpieces<numPoints

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand last sentence. New points (circles) lie on old segments in my implementation.